# Python: Need guidance with a dropdown list

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I took over a web app from a user who left the company and I don't know what I'm doing. Basically I have a site table that has 2 columns I need, site and name. I want the name to display in the dropdown menu and site to be the value of the dropdown. This what it looks like now:

In the views template

```
def getWarehouseList():
warehouse_list = ['Warehouse'] + pd.DataFrame.from_records(Site.objects.filter(active=True).values('site')).sort_values('site')['site'].tolist()
return tuple([(choice, choice) for choice in warehouse_list])
```

In the html/view:

```
<select id="warehouse\_drop" name = "warehouse"> {% for warehouse in warehouse\_list %} <option value ="{{warehouse}}">{{ warehouse }}</option> {% endfor %} </select>
```

How can I change the option value to be "name" instead of "site" (warehouse). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your must response all Site object fields in context to template, not only site value. Your view function should be like below:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def getWarehouseList(request):
    context={
        'warehouse_list' : Site.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('site') # you can give any string for 'warehouse_list'. It may be 'site_list' or anything else but you must use same name in html file 
    }
    return render(request, 'xxxx.html', context=context)
```

where 'xxxx.html' is your html file name. It may be in templates folder. If there are any inner folders, you must give like 'folderpath/xxxx.html'.

in 'xxxx.html' file:

```
<select id="warehouse_drop" name = "warehouse"> 
   {% for warehouse in warehouse_list %} 
      <option value ="{{warehouse.name}}">{{warehouse.site}}</option> 
   {% endfor %} 
</select>
```